# screen resolution for my monitor not listed

Tags: 11.10, intel-graphics, resolution

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot. Everything works fine except for the screen resolution for my monitor which is wrong. In the system settings I can change it but the one that goes with my monitor is not listed.

In system info, the graphics driver is unknown. My graphics card is:

```
sudo lshw -C video

  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 10
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:42 memory:fdf00000-fdf7ffff ioport:f400(size=8) memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fda00000-fdafffff
```